# "Russell set" examples (LPL 15.65 exercise)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Language, Proof & Logic course, after they prove that for each set $b$ there exists a set $c$ which is a subset of $b$ but not a member of $b$, they call such a set *the Russell set for b* and give a following exercise:

> What is the Russell set for each of the following sets?
>
> 1. $\{\varnothing\}$
> 2. A set $a$ satisfying $a = \{ a \}$
> 3. A set $\{1, a\}$ where $a = \{ a \}$
> 4. The set of all sets

That is given in the context of an

**Axiom** Axiom of Unrestricted Comprehension

$$\forall z_1 \ldots \forall z_n \, \exists a \, \forall x \, 
[ x \in a \leftrightarrow P(x) ]$$

and the Axiom of Extensionality, i.e. in the Naive context (if it is appropriate to call it so)

I would like to know if my answers I correct, or there are more ideas behind it:

> 1. $b = \{\varnothing\}$

$b$ itself

> 2. A set $a$ satisfying $a = \{ a \}$

It should be a set:

$$\{ x \vert x \in a \land x \notin x \} $$

Which gives us the set

$c = \varnothing$

$\varnothing \subseteq a, \varnothing \notin a$

Does such a set do the job?

> 3. A set $\{1, a\}$ where $a = \{ a \}$

That one is similar to the example in the text:
$$ c = \{ 1 \} $$ seems to be a valid example because it couldn't be that $c = a$ as it would violate the given condition on $a$

> 4. $a = $ The set of all sets

As I understand, the expected answer is just

$$\{ x \vert x \: \text{is a set} \land x \notin x \} $$ which leads us directly to the paradox (inconsistency of the Axioms) if we also consider that such a set is a set and therefore should be an element of $a$.

Comment: Looks right to me! (Although it should be noted that the use of the term "Russell set" here is not standardized, as far as I know; it generally refers specifically to the (putative) set of all sets not containing themselves.)

Comment: In the formal language of ZF (and ZFC) there is no word "set". There are just sentences about things that do or don't exist...... The instance $\exists a\,\forall x\, (x\in a \iff x\not \in x)$ of Naive Comprehension immediately implies Russell's Paradox without any additional axioms.